# Tool to generate documentation for components in a React project with their propTypes?

Tags: reactjs

Is their a tool that will allow me to generate (preferably graphic) documentation/diagram of React components in my project, along with their propTypes, reading in their propTypes (and possibly defaultProps)?  If it were a hierarchical diagram, so much the better.  I found some possibilities, such as `react-monocle` but I don't know they fit the bill, and many don't seem to be maintained.  Thanks for any leads!

Comment: https://github.com/Polyconseil/react-doks

Answer (score 1):

React Sight is the way to go!
https://github.com/React-Sight/React-Sight

Comment: Thanks -- I'm getting "Cannot find React Triggering a setState() ussually fixes this" -- I have no easy way to trigger a re-render or set state.  I see (from the issues) that a lot of people are having this problem.